# using boto to download files but not to local machine

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to use boto to download files from S3 bucket but actually the default download goes to my local machine, once i uploaded my code to the server, kept downloaded files to my local machine. and i want to download it to the server, not local. any advice

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What do you mean by "the server"? Can you run the download command from the server rather than your local machine? Have you considered using the Command Line Interface (aws.amazon.com/cli)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out It has a direct way of uploading and downloading the files to s3.

```
http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/upload-and-download-files-tofrom-amazon-s3-using-pythondjango/
```